# Will I have problems maintaining a bike from the UK in the US?

Tags: maintenance, uk, us

I'm moving to the US from the UK and am considering taking my fairly average hybrid road bike with me. It's nothing special but I quite like it and the cost of taking it on a plane doesn't seem to be too much. However, I'm concerned I won't be able to buy new parts etc.

Are sizes for things like brake pads, chains, gear sets, etc. common between the two countries?

Edit: Sounds like this will be fine. As suggested though, I'll add it's a lower-end Specialized Sirrus.

Comment: It really depends on bike brand. Shimano components are equal everywhere, bur things like Brompton hubs might be harder to track down.

Comment: Adding the make/model would make the question easier to answer (although less general).

Comment: There is absolutely no problem to shop on the British online stores. The shipping to US by Royal Mail is not cost too much and sometimes it's free. The sites like http://www.probikekit.com and others specifically working on US market and, for example, tires are cheaper there. So, there is no problem to buy specific 'British' parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's from one of the big brands (Trek, Specialized, Giant etc.) then you should be fine. Only difference between one bought in the UK and one in the US would be brakes mounted opposite way round (i.e. front brake operated by left lever rather than the right), and maybe paintjob!

Comment: Even so, you can always order parts through the internet these days if necessary. I'd guess even smaller brands use the same parts in the UK and US these days. The issue would be probably with bike age - for example, maintaining an old Raleigh Twenty can be a hassle on either side of the pond, though you may be able to get more parts a bit easier in the UK given that more were probably sold in the UK (or you can just use Sheldon Brown's work arounds for the Raleigh Twenty, such as for the BB). And the brakes cables can easily be swapped, of course - the shifters are on the same side.

Comment: less the brand of the bike, more the brand of the groupset